# How to add additional photos to a status update

Tags: facebook, photo-sharing, facebook-photos

I created a Facebook status update with three photos. I'd like to add one more. Note that I did not create an album, I simply uploaded all three photos at the time of creating the Facebook status update. I can delete photos... but don't see a way to add one.

[image: Facebook Status Update Edit Dialog]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you posted it, you can’t add a new photo to a status update. The only moment when you can add more photos to a status update is between the time one or more photos are uploaded and the one you click *Post* (see picture below).

[image]

The only thing you can do is to delete the first pictures and re-upload them together with the fourth.

(FYI: the photos you upload directly (as status updates) are grouped in the album called *Timeline Photos*.)

Comment: By "delete the first pictures and re-upload them together with the fourth.", do you mean to say I'd have to create a new status update with four pictures?  Or that I can somehow update the existing status update?

Comment: Exactly. You can’t add new photos, you can only rotate the existing one(s) and edit the text of the respective status update—if there is any in the first place.